# How to find file attribute changes by comparing two BTRFS subvolumes?

Tags: backup, btrfs

Since disabling CoW on some folders (like database folders) crucial for a hard drive, I also need to backup that information. However, as of v5.10 `btrfs send/receive` still ignores this information. Recursively checking every file with `lsattr -R` is very ineffective.

How does backup systems that relies on BTRFS handle this problem? Can we find the attribute changes between given subvolumes effectively?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way I can think of is iterating over the list generated by

```
btrfs send --no-data | btrfs receive --dump
```

to check only the files with `utimes` changes: (see [find-attribute-diff.sh](https://github.com/ceremcem/smith-sync/blob/master/find-attribute-diff.sh))

```bsh
changed_utime=$(btrfs send -q --no-data -p "$SNAPSHOT_OLD" "$SNAPSHOT_NEW" \
    | sudo btrfs receive --dump \
    | grep ^utimes \
    | awk '{print $2}' \
    | sort \
    | uniq)

>&2 echo "INFO: Examining $(echo "$changed_utime" | wc | awk '{print $1}') files"

while read -r _f; do
    file=$(echo $_f | cut -d'/' -f3-)
    [[ -z $file ]] && continue
    _old=$SNAPSHOT_OLD/$file
    _new=$SNAPSHOT_NEW/$file
    [ \( -d "$_old" -o -f "$_old" \) -a ! -L "$_old" ] || continue
    [ \( -d "$_new" -o -f "$_new" \) -a ! -L "$_new" ] || continue
    old_attr=$(lsattr -d $_old | awk '{print $1}')
    new_attr=$(lsattr -d $_new | awk '{print $1}')
    [[ "$old_attr" != "$new_attr" ]] && echo "$old_attr    $new_attr    $file"
done <<< "$changed_utime"
```